# how to know this query related to which block

Tags: views, blocks

I have a website with a very large number of blocks, some of them have been created using Views module. now i am seeing in slow query log some queries generated by Views like

```
SELECT DISTINCT(node.nid) AS nid, 
  node.type AS node_type, 
node.vid AS node_vid, 
node.title AS node_title, 
node.language AS node_language, 
node.created AS node_created 
FROM node node 
LEFT JOIN term_node term_node ON node.vid = term_node.vid AND term_node.tid = 193 
LEFT JOIN term_node term_node2 ON node.vid = term_node2.vid AND term_node2.tid = 194 
LEFT JOIN term_node term_node3 ON node.vid = term_node3.vid AND term_node3.tid != 194 
WHERE (node.type in ('article')) AND (node.status = 1) AND (node.language in ('ar')) AND (term_node.tid IS NULL) AND (term_node2.tid IS NULL) AND (term_node3.tid = 0) GROUP BY nid ORDER BY node_created DESC ;
```

Now, is there any way to know this query related to which block? i couldn't figure it out by checking in preview query of views!!

Answer (score 1):

There is some hint on last line. the block in showing Article(node type) which are published to site and created in arabic language.

So, remind that where u seen this kind of content block in the site.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is helpful you are convenient with mysql. Please follow the steps to find which view this query is  running

In this query you have mentioned content_type = article, whatever option we have provided in view it can be stored in views_display table. So you can use this query which view is related with query.

`SELECT *
FROM`views_display
`WHERE`display_options`LIKE '%article%'`

Then you will get vid of that view then you can check views_view table for identify view name.

If you are getting more than a vid, you can find which view is appearing your page where did you get this slow query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, in fact i was looking for such answer and i know this about display_options already. but searching for article will not give any benefit for me :( so i have tried to search for like '%term_node3%' but with no luck as well

Answer (score 1):

There is a more definitive way. If you suspect a particular block, you can edit the view, and under 'Advanced -> Query Settings' you can add a comment to the query like 'This query came from blockname.' and the comment will be appended to the sql.